# Changing all "[" to \llbracket

Tags: stmaryrd

Is there a way to change all `[` and `]`s in a document to `\llbracket` and `\rrbracket`? Without modifying the text?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please provide a minimum working example (MWE) showing which packages you're loading and what precisely you're looking to achieve. I'm assuming you can't literally want all `[` and `]` instances turned into `\llbracket` and `\rrbracket`, respectively, as that would wreak havoc on commands such as `\section[short title]{long title}`, right?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'd like them to be turned into \llbracket and \rrbracket in \text and mathmode.

Comment: You can do this easily enough: `\catcode\`\[=\active \def[{\ensuremath{\llbracket}}` but as @Mico says that will break any commands that use [ and ] for optional arguments.  Can  you explain why you can't / don't want to change the source?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can “easily” change `[` and `]` to mean `\llbracket` and `\rrbracket` in math mode:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{stmaryrd}

\begingroup
\catcode`[=\active \catcode`]=\active

% Define a meaning for active [ and ]
\gdef[{\llbracket} \gdef]{\rrbracket}

% Now take care of the \delcode of [ and ] for \left and \right
% First a temporary macro
\def\getdelim#1#2#3#4\relax{"#4}
% Use the temporary macro to get the right delcodes out of
% the meaning of \llbracket and \rrbracket
\global\delcode`[=\expandafter\getdelim\llbracket\relax
\global\delcode`]=\expandafter\getdelim\rrbracket\relax
\endgroup

% make [ and ] math active
\mathcode`\[="8000
\mathcode`\]="8000

\begin{document}
Here's a formula $a[b]=c[d]$; the brackets even change size with
\verb|\left| and \verb|\right|:
\[
\left[\frac{1}{2}\right]
\]
\end{document}
```

For text mode square brackets there is no way to do this automatically, because `[` and `]` has a syntactical meaning for many LaTeX commands.

[image]

Comment: But this will affect commands taking optional arguments within math-mode, right?

Comment: @A.Ellett No, it won't: try `\sqrt[3]{8}`